# Calculate the duration of group of Bond ETFs

Tags: bond, etf, duration, bond-portfolio

Is it correct to get the weighted average of a bunch of bond ETFs to get the duration? Is it theoretical correct to say that.

I have 6M AGG (duration 8.39), 30M BND (duration 8.7), 60M SHY (duration 1.98), 10 VTIP (duration 2.7), 5M BIV (duration 7.3). So my duration for this portfolio is (6/111 * 8.39) + (30/111 * 8.7) + ... + (5/111 * 7.3) = 4.439

Is that the correct way to calculate the duration for the portfolio?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: If, instead of duration, you measured interest rate risk as the P&L from interest rate change, then everything would be clearer.

Comment: I believe this is what people in industry do. I do not think doing "market cap" weighted duration you get the theoretical correct one. To retrieve the pure duration of the portfolio, you should treat the weighted cash-flows as a big bond and construct analytics on it. This can be heavy for a computer (especially when you have callable and perpetuals) and that is why people get away with market cap weighted duration.

Comment: If your "duration" metric is "modified duration", then this method is correct. Because modified duration is delta-price/delta-yield. IE it's like combining equity portfolios with different betas. The problem here (as with equities) is that the yields of the things you're combining may not be aligned (just as the returns of two equity indices will not be). AGG and SHY track different yields here, that behave differently. You can measure the duration of both IF you're happy to assume that they coincide. Else you need a model for how the behaviour of these yields coincide/differ.